# How can one add batch mechanism to the input function in Tensorflow tutorial overcoming tf.Sparsetensor objects?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, python-3.5

How can one add `batch` mechanism to the `input_fn` in the [TensorFlow Wide & Deep Learning Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep) overcoming that some features are represented as `tf.Sparsetensor` objects?

I have made many attempts around adding `tf.train.slice_input_producer` and `tf.train.batch`to the original code (see below), but have failed miserably so far.

I would like to keep the global working of that input_fn as it is handy while while training and evaluating the model.

Can someone help, please?

```
def input_fn(df):
    # Creates a dictionary mapping from each continuous feature column name (k) to
    # the values of that column stored in a constant Tensor.
    continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values)
                       for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
    # Creates a dictionary mapping from each categorical feature column name (k)
    # to the values of that column stored in a tf.SparseTensor.
    categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df[k].size)],
                                           values=df[k].values,
                                           shape=[df[k].size, 1]) for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}

    # Merges the two dictionaries into one.
    feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols.items() + categorical_cols.items())
    # Converts the label column into a constant Tensor.
    labels = tf.constant(df[LABEL_COLUMN].values)

    '''
    Changes from here: 
    '''
    features_slices, features_slices = tf.train.slice_input_producer([features_cols, labels], ...)

    features_batches, labels_batches =  tf.train.batch([features_slices, features_slices], ...)

    # Returns the feature and label batches.
    return features_batches, labels_batches
```